# What does a Property Setter correspond to when used in conjunction with ControlTemplates?

Tags: wpf

I have the following Style (stripped for brevity) and have some questions based on it. To my understanding, if a ControlTemplate replaces the entire visual tree of a control for which the Style is based on, what effect do the property Setters have then?

In this example, don't the property Setters for FontSize, Margin, Height etc. correspond to the respective properties on the CheckBox itself? If you replace the Template property of a control, what will these Setters then correspond to if the CheckBox is no longer rendering it's default appearance?

```
<Style x:Key="KeyName" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 1 0" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="18" />
    ... common property setters etc.

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                <Border>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Ellipse Name="Ellipse" Width="7" Height="7" />
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                        </Trigger.Setters>
                    </Trigger>
                        ... custom triggers etc ...
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

They are a way to provide an initial default value for properties on the object that's being styled, they don't auto force anything on the Template for you. They can however be used in the control template.

Values that are set using the setters in a style can be overridden by local values in the xaml. for example.

This xaml file draws a single label that has had it's style altered to include a grid that takes on the background color, I've defaulted the color to red in the setter and it appears as red.

```
<Window x:Class="ContextMenu.MainWindow"      
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"      
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Label>Test</Label>
</Window>
```

if I was to change the label line to blue on the instance of the label, you can see this overrides the setter.

```
<Window x:Class="ContextMenu.MainWindow"      
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"      
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Label Background="Blue">Test</Label>
</Window>
```

Comment: So does that mean if a value that is set in a property Setter is not referenced in a TemplateBinding (or RelativeSource) then that property will have no effect on the visual tree elements in the ControlTemplate or do certain values (depending on the property's DependencyFrameworkMetadata) still flow down the through the tree? eg would the inner TextBlock inside the ControlTemplate in your example inherit the Margin and FontSize properties from the Setters, if they were set?